# ccing using SendGrid Service in Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, sendgrid

Trying to use SendGrid Service in Bluemix coding in Node.js. I use the addCc() method to add an address to cc to. I get no error msg and the mail is delivered to the main address, but nothing gets sent to the cc:ed address. And if I look ath the top of the mail going to the main recipient I can see the cc address there. Does anyone know if there is a bug or limitation in using cc with SendGrid?

Best Regards

W

Comment: I'll assume you're using the 'sendgrid' npm module.  What version?  Could it be that you're hitting https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/issues/162 ?  Looks like it should be fixed in the recent release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common error is to pass an array to the addCc() function when it expects a string.  Using v2.0.0 of the 'sendgrid' npm module, the code below will correctly send an email which cc's 'jennifer@electric.co'.

As mentioned in the comment above, verify that you're not hitting issue https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/issues/162

```
// Pre-req: get the SendGrid credentials for username and password
// from VCAP_SERVICES into the 'user' and 'pass' vars
var sendgrid = require('sendgrid')(user, pass);
var email = new sendgrid.Email({
    to:      'fargo.north@electric.co',
    from:    'bronco.bruce@electric.co',
    subject: 'SendGrid Test',
    text:    'This is a SendGrid test'
};

// add a cc address as a single string
email.addCc('jennifer@electric.co');

sendgrid.send(email, function(err, json) {
    if (err) { 
        return console.error(err); 
    }
    console.log(json);
}
```

Comment: I used 1.9.2. I solved my problem by directly update the variables (eg. mail.cc = ccAdress)  instead of using the methods. Thnx everyone ofr hints and tips. Much appreciated W